# Why i use .after() to delay call a function in a loop not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, delay

Why i use .after() to delay call a function in a loop not working properly.
The first loop in .after() delayed call function show_letter() . But  after the first loop, it just call the function without any delay.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

window = Tk()
# window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


#
def show_letter():
    randomletter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

    print(randomletter)
    label.config(text=randomletter)
  


def delay_show():
    for i in range(200):
        window.after(2000, show_letter)


label = Label(window,
              text='',
              font=('arial', 40),
              )


label.place(relx=0.5, rely=.4, )

delay_show()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: We need to see a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `window.after(i, show_letter)` should do what you like.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: `window.after(i, show_letter)` the each letter for only a few milliseconds.  I don't think that's what the OP wants. For example, the first will show for 1ms, the second for 2ms, etc. It will be imperceptible.

Comment: @BryanOakley True, I must admit I didn't got the idea of this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
def delay_show():
    for i in range(200):
        window.after(2000, show_letter)
```

What this does is schedule the first call to `show_letter` in 2 seconds. Then it *also* schedules the second call in two seconds. Not two seconds after the first call but two seconds after the start of the loop. Then the third call is *also* two seconds after the start of the loop.

In other words, all of the calls are all scheduled to start at the same time, in 2 seconds.

The fix is simple: multiply 2000 times the loop increment so that the first call is in 2 seconds, the next in 4, the next in 6, and so on.

```
def delay_show():
    for i in range(200):
        window.after(2000*i, show_letter)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Now i understand . I also went googled more information about the after() function. This is how it counts the time. I post it here in case anyone also encounter this problem.The Tkinter after() is one of the methods for the Tkinter package, and this method is used to calculate the time intervals for the functions in the application parallel. It calculates the time using milliseconds format whether the widget seems delayed since the Tkinter is a GUI-based library. If we have no particular values of the explicit statement, it goes to the default state behavior.

Comment: @bingru: _"this method is used to calculate the time intervals for the functions in the application parallel. "_ - that is incorrect. `after` doesn't run code in parallel.